# plotting correlation matrix using python

Tags: python

I want to plot the correlation matrix using python. I have tried with the following script

```
  corr_matrix=np.corrcoef(vector)
  imshow(corr_matrix, interpolation='bilinear')
  colorbar()
  show()
```

The dimension of the matrix is 2500X2500. The above code produces a matrix of full of dots. But I want smooth surface. How do I get that.

Best
Sudipta

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "smooth surface" and *why* do you want to visualize your correlation matrix that way?

Here are two useful examples for visualizing [correlation] matrices. Both contain an explanation as well as example code for matplotlib.

1. Square grid pseudocolor plot 
   http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/10/visualizing-correlation-matrices.html
2. Hinton Diagram
   http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/HintonDiagrams

**Update:** 
To supplement my comment, here's a pseudocolor visualization of a 1000x1000 correlation matrix, which didn't encounter memory issues on my humble laptop:

[image]

Note that although row 20 is correlated to other variables and row 40 is correlated to row 80, in the style of the GlowingPython example, yet this information is obscured by the sheer size of the matrix.

Comment: the pcolor() method is out of memory for my matrix. It works for small matrix (say 10X10) but for the large matrix it is not working. Is there any other method which work similar to the pcolor()?

Comment: I'm not sure looking at a pcolor chart of a matrix that large (2500x2500) will tell you anything useful. Having said that, how large do you get before the memory error? Perhaps consider plotting a quarter of the matrix at a time?

Comment: See my update which contains a pic of a 1000x1000 corr matrix.

Comment: Same script as in the first link (GlowingPython), I just changed the size.

Comment: But, I have tried with that for the large matrix (3000X30000). It was not working. The function imshow that I have used in my script is working well but the origin of the 2d map is (0,n) instead of (0,0). How do I resolve that.

Comment: `imshow` is generally used to display images stored as arrays, which is why you are seeing the origin at (0,n). // Again, the important thing is what you are trying to accomplish. You are probably not going to be able to spot a correlation by visually rendering a 3k x 3k correlation matrix -- that was the point of my example. // Did you try splitting up the matrix and plotting separately as suggested earlier?

Comment: The function pcolor() can't handle the large matrix but I haven't tried with the splitting up the matrix. I haven't found that in your earlier message. Can you please write that script in your reply message?

Comment: @user1964587 - On a side note, use `pcolormesh` (or just `imshow` as you're already doing, but with `interpolation='nearest'`) instead of `pcolor` for large arrays. (`pcolormesh` is limited to rectangular cells, whereas pcolor isn't, thus the speedup.) The advantage (or disadvantage) to using `pcolormesh` or `pcolor` over `imshow` when displaying regular grids is mostly that the former produce vector output. At any rate, `pcolormesh` should solve your problems with the large matrix.

Comment: Sudipta, I didn't write code to break up the array, it was just a suggestion in an earlier comment. You can slice the numpy matrix or use something like `numpy.split()` to do that. Just be careful to use the same scale on each plot. But you might want to follow up on @JoeKington's tip first.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the columns based on the values obtained in the correlation matrix.